# SFML C++ setting a texture in the constructor

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new to C++ and I'm making Space Invaders with SFML. I did the basic logic just using SFML shapes and colors, but now i want to apply textures to the shapes. For example this is my Projectile class:

```
class Projectile
{
sf::RectangleShape projectileShape;
Location projectileLoc;

public:
explicit Projectile(int x, int y);
void shootShip();
void shootEnemy();
sf::RectangleShape getShape();
void setTexture(sf::Texture & texture);
Location getLocation();
void overboard(std::vector<Projectile> & projectiles);
};
```

now what I want to do in the constructor is:

```
Projectile::Projectile(int x, int y)
{
sf::Texture projectileTexture;
projectileTexture.loadFromFile("path to the texture");
projectileShape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 30));
projectileShape.setTexture(&projectileTexture);
projectileLoc.x = x;
projectileLoc.y = y;
projectileShape.setPosition(projectileLoc.x, projectileLoc.y);
}
```

and then in the main function I have a vector of Projectile objects that I draw using the sf::RectangleShape getShape() function that returns projectileShape, but it draws it without the texture what Am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [white square problem](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php). You have dangling reference to your texture. `projectileShape.setTexture(&projectileTexture);` this storing a pointer to texture, which is local inside the function.

Comment: `projectileTexture` probably needs to be a class member.

Comment: Ok I understand now how do I make this pointer available to the rest? should I use a unique_ptr? or is there a more simple and elegant solution?

Comment: I expect you can move the `sf::Texture projectileTexture;` line to right after `sf::RectangleShape projectileShape;` which will make it a class member instead of a local variable and extend its lifetime to that of the `Projectile` class

Comment: Did it still doesn't work.

Comment: Even you do `projectileTexture` as a data member, you can still have a dangling reference because you didn't provide copy operations for `Projectile` so its default generated versions will do a shallow copy of texture stored inside `RectangleShape` which is wrong. Provide MCVE, showing how `Projectile` instances are used.

Comment: One other option (after the rule of 3 or 5) is maybe your path is wrong here: `projectileTexture.loadFromFile("path to the texture");`

Comment: This is where i store the Projectiles 'std::vector<Projectile> shipProjectiles', then in the while window.isOpen loop i do a for loop where i call the window.draw(projectile.getShape()) function.

Comment: The sf:Texture class appears to properly handle the rule of 3/5: [https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php) so I believe the default shallow copy would work.

Comment: Maybe I'm drawing it the wrong way but I don't think so what I did yesterday was I createrd a draw method inside the Projectile class that I pass the main window to. If i draw the shape with that method the program works and it draws the texture, but after a few seconds it crashes and I get 'pure virtual method called'